# formatting File name of attachment in vf email templates

Tags: visualforce, email-template

I'm using VF Email templates while sending email via workflow.
I want to customize file name of attachment which is sent along with email.

```
 <messaging:attachment filename="MyFileName.csv" >
```

In above line, i want to include today's date but if I do :

```
 <messaging:attachment filename="MyFileName{!Today()}.csv" >
```

then in email i recieve , it show something  number along with file name like this : Seems, is converting date to number while sending email

> 'MyFileName611120.csv'

What could I do to resolve this ?

Comment: Hi ... .I have tried the same in dev org.. and it's coming correct for me ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are most likely receiving the locale-formatted date string. If you leverage the `TEXT()` function within the formula you'll get the date formatted as the standard YYYY-MM-DD instead.

```
<messaging:attachment filename="Test{!TEXT(TODAY())}.csv">
```

If you want to control the formatting further you might consider using the individual functions to extract parts of the date and recombine them as you desire.

```
TEXT(MONTH(TODAY())) & "_" & TEXT(DAY(TODAY())) & "_" & TEXT(YEAR(TODAY()))
```

Answer (score 0):

.I have tried the same in dev org.. and it's coming correct for me ..

```
<messaging:attachment filename="Test{!Today()}.csv ">
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for reply. you've put "_" in between filename and Date. But screenshot is not showing it. Just want to confirm, if this is same what you've tried?

Comment: Hi-  Also just small thing ..did you also try receiving email ? Probably  In Salesforce UI , it is coming fine while in email, it is giving problem

Comment: hi..  I have also tested with mail... I have received the mail and attachment name is coming fine...